# Why is this canvas one pixel too large?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

**MCVE**

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

def print_click(event):
    print event.x, event.y

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', print_click)

root.mainloop()
```

**Issue**

Clicking the canvas on the very top left prints `(0, 0)`.
Clicking the canvas on the very bottom right prints `(100, 100)`. I expected `(99, 99)`.

This means the canvas is actually 101 pixels wide and high, not 100.

In my real program, I am showing an array (as an image) on the canvas and need the precise click position. If that position does not exist in the underlying image (i.e. `(100, 100)` for an 100x100 array), the program will crash.

**Questions**

1. Am I doing something wrong creating the canvas? Why is it one wider and higher than expected?
2. Is the simple fix here to just subtract 1 from `width` and `height` whenever setting up a canvas that needs to have width `width` and height `height`?

Comment: Have you tried reproducing your results after explicitly setting `borderwidth` and `highlightthickess` to zero? Those both contribute to the overall width and height of the canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley No, I did not. But I will try immediately.

Comment: @BryanOakley `highlightthickness=0` solves the issue! Thank you so much, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other things that contribute to the overall width and height of a widget besides just the `width` and `height` attributes. For example, both `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` contribute to the overall size of the widget. Since you aren't setting those to zero, you're relying on the defaults for your platform, and those defaults apparently aren't zero.

You need to explicitly set those attributes to zero:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
```